# Forms Authentication cookie with Sitecore

Tags: security, authentication, cookies

Does it require to explicitly set authentication cookie after authenticating user via Sitecore Authentication Manager?

```
if (Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(
                fullUsername,
                password,
                false))
            {
                //Does it require to explicitly set set authentication cookie here?
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that one does not have to authentication cookie after calling 
`Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login()`

FormAuthentication.SetAuthCookie  will be called after successful login.

Source

https://cprakash.com/2014/09/12/sitecore-form-authentication-cookie-renewal-sliding-expiration/